# Why does lxml not return the text associated with this html element?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I'm new to using python for parsing through html, and I'm having trouble. I'm trying to write a short script to grab a number from a website each day. However, instead of returning a number like I want it to, the code just returns `None`.

The following webpage displays the number of bikes that ride through a particular area each day: http://eco-public.com/public2/?id=100023038. I'm trying to write a short python script to record the number of bikes that rode by "yesterday" (which is a different number everyday, typically between 500 and 1,500). When I inspect that element of the webpage, I see that it's xpath is: `//*[@id="region-lastDay"]/div/p[2]/text()`. However, when I try to use the following code to return the number, it instead returns the value `None`.

```
import lxml.html as lh
import urllib2
doc = lh.parse(urlopen('http://eco-public.com/public2/?id=100023038'))
daily = doc.xpath('//*[@id="region-lastDay"]')
for i in daily:
    print i.text
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the original request your browser makes to that URL (e.g. with Developer Tools in Chrome or Firefox, or just printing out the value of `urlopen(...).read()`), you will see that `region-lastDay` element looks like this:

```
    <!-- Key Numbers -->
    <div class="row" id="keyrow">
        <div id="region-total"  class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"></div>
        <div id="region-lastDay" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" ></div>
    </div>
```

It is indeed empty, because the element is being filled in after the initial page load with an AJAX call that is returning JSON (observed via Chrome's Developer Tools -> Network tab):

[image: Chrome developer tools showing ajax call]

So instead of using `lxml`, you need to use `json` to parse the response from the URL being used for the AJAX call:

- http://www.eco-public.com/api/h7q239dd/data/periode/100023038?begin=20150623&end=20150801&step=4

Grab the final element from the JSON, like so:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> import json
>>> response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.eco-public.com/api/h7q239dd/data/periode/100023038?begin=20150623&end=20150801&step=4")
>>> data = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf8'))
>>> data[-1]
{'comptage': 695, 'timestamp': 1438380000000, 'date': '2015-08-01 00:00:00.0'}
```

You also will probably want to adjust the `start` and `end` params in the URL to get data from other days.

Answer (score 0):

The `div` is empty in the html code.

```
<div id="region-lastDay" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" ></div>
```

And it is filled with javascript. Javascript part is cannot be handled by `lxml`. You need packages that can handle javascript part ([`selenium`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) for example).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


driver = webdriver.Firefox()  # OR  Chrome() / PhantomJS() / ...
driver.get('http://eco-public.com/public2/?id=100023038')
xpath = '//*[@id="region-lastDay"]/div'
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
daily = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
for i in daily:
    print i.text
# driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question; however, I was having an issue loading a Javascript generated page because lxml grabs data before JS load and I have found a solution.

This solution will require that you use these imports:

```
import sys  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  
from lxml import html
```

and this code to wait for page render

```
#Take this class for granted.Just use result of rendering.
class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit()
```

Now, once you have this you can start scraping like so:

```
url = 'http://pycoders.com/archive/'  
r = Render(url)  
result = r.frame.toHtml()
#This step is important.Converting QString to Ascii for lxml to process
archive_links = html.fromstring(str(result.toAscii()))
print archive_links
```

Using the Render class you can load a page and convert it to Ascii for lxml.
I have "print archive_links" so you can see the structure it returns, you don't need this.

Now to scrape the information you collected you can use lxml.

```
#Now using correct Xpath we are fetching URL of archives
archive_links = tree.xpath('//divass="campaign"]/a/@href')
print archive_links
```

All of this code put together from top to bottom will get you a loaded page with JS generated elements and allow you to grab them with lxml.

Source of content: https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/